# Query host components template from inside directive

Tags: angular

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2jmh6)

Can I use queries like `ContentChild(ren)` or `ViewChild(ren)` that would query `HelloComponent`'s local template variable `#queryMeFromDirective`

like:
`@ViewChild('queryMeFromDirective', {static: true}) myEl: ElementRef`

Can I get the same results when using this inside `QueryDirective`.

I can inject the host like

`@Host() @Self() @Optional() public helloComponent : HelloComponent`

So I should get access somehow :/.

Any ideas?

- I know I could give the local varable into an input of the directive.
- I know I could do the querying inside the component and then access a component property from the directive.

This question is about querying the host components view **DIRECTLY** from within a directive.